# Property 'copy' does not exist on type 'Clipboard'

Tags: angular, clipboard

I'm trying to copy a text when a button is clicked. I tried following Angular's documentation (https://material.angular.io/cdk/clipboard/overview#programmatically-copy-a-string) but my terminal is giving me the following error when compiling:

> Property 'copy' does not exist on type 'Clipboard'

Here's my .ts file:

```js
export class myComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private clipboard: Clipboard) {}
  ngOnInit(): void {}

  copyTest() {
    this.clipboard.copy("test"); // Property 'copy' does not exist on type 'Clipboard'.
  }
}
```

Here's my .html file:

```html
<button [cdkCopyToClipboard]="copyTest()">Click to copy</button>
```

And here's my app.module.ts file:

```js
import { ClipboardModule } from "@angular/cdk/clipboard";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    myComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    ClipboardModule,
  ]
})
```

Any ideas why this error is occurring?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You must be missing the correct import for Clipboard.

Try adding: `import { Clipboard } from '@angular/cdk/clipboard';` to your .ts file as well as your app.module.ts.

There is an interface Clipboard as well which your IDE probably accepts as valid TS.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
<button [cdkCopyToClipboard]="copyTest('Test!')">Click to copy</button>

copyTest(test: string) {
    this.clipboard.copy(test);
  }
```